# Why make more than one python file for the same program?

Tags: python, windows, pygame

I have been making a games using pygame and python and I don't need to make more, separate python files to run my game, but when I look at other peoples programs, they have different files that all work in conjunction with each other for their program to work, why not have all or most of the coding in one file?

I use python 3.2.5 and the corresponding pygame

--- Me in the future --- I apologise for asking this question I didn't know exactly what this website was for and how to ask questions ect. I know know that this website inst for opinions.

Comment: Because one big file is one big mess.

Comment: modularization is the standard way developers fight against complexity.

Comment: Because one of the key paradigms in programming is modularity - i.e. keeping functionality in discrete blocks in order to try to improve readability, reliability and reduce complexity - having separate files makes modularity simpler to implement

Comment: Just FYI: this is the wrong place to put this question.

Comment: Would *you* prefer to edit 20kloc (20 thousand lines of code) in a single file with everything mashed together in a single package or in 30 ~700loc files arranged by logic grouping? For a very small bit of code it doesn't matter, but as the code grows separate modules/files become invaluable for organization and maintainability. (Also, a 20kloc program is often still "very small".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People do this because it makes the program more **readable**.
While writing some code you have to understand the difficulty of the people who will **maintain your code**.

The main advantages of making it in separate files are:

- **modularity**- By using separate files different modules of the program can be separated into different files. This has many advantages. Whenever a problem occur in some part of the code you can look straight into that file.
- **Readability**- Splitting program into different files helps in making it more readable and beautiful.
- **easy to maintain**- Similar to the advantage told in modularity. Whenever some part of the program needs to be updated it can be done easily.
- **code reuse**- If the program is split carefully into different modules, you can use the same code later when a similar problem has to be solved